# Problem: The append() method does not keep the original order of strings in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a function `create_profanity_output()` (see below for the whole code), in which each profanity from a transcript file is appended to a list, followed by the timestamp and censor characters. I want to **keep the order** in which the elements appear in the transcript.

But my problem is that the order of the appended elements is **not** the same as in the transcript. I thought that `append()` would add an element always at the end of the list (which would correspond to the original order). But it seems like the profanities are sorted alphabetically, even though I have not used the `sorted()` function.

To be more precise, the current (unwanted) output looks like this:

```
# Current output in wrong order.
[['fart', '00:00:03,950', '00:00:06,840', '****'],
 ['damn', '00:00:03,950', '00:00:06,840', '****'],
 ['damn', '00:00:03,950', '00:00:06,840', '****'],
 ['erotic', '00:00:03,950', '00:00:06,840', '****'],
```

But the elements' appearance in the file is 1) fart, 2) erotic, 3) damn, 4) damn, so the desired output would be:

```
# Target output in correct order.
[['fart', '00:00:03,950', '00:00:06,840', '****'],
 ['erotic', '00:00:03,950', '00:00:06,840', '****'],
 ['damn', '00:00:03,950', '00:00:06,840', '****'],
 ['damn', '00:00:03,950', '00:00:06,840', '****'],
```

This problem also occurs when there are more profanities in the transcript. As soon as they have the same timestamp, they are sorted alphabetically instead of keeping their original order. I have tried sorting the list like:

`sorted_output = sorted(profanity_output, reversed=True)`,

`sorted_output = sorted(profanity_output, reversed=False)`,

`sorted_output = sorted(profanity_output, key=lambda x: x[0])`,

and the like, but without achieving my goal.

I know this is a trivial question. But the profanities' order mustn't be alphabetical. Has anyone an idea why `append()` is acting like this and how I can solve this problem?

The whole code:

```
def create_profanity_output():
    """Create a list 'profanity_output' which shall contain each profanity,
    its timestamp and the default censor characters ('****')."""
    profanity_output = []

    # Define censor characters that occur in the transcript.
    censor_chars = "****"

    # Create lists with transcript data.
    line_numbers = []
    timestamps = []
    text_lines = []

    # Get lines from the transcript that contain strings according to the
    # following pattern: 'line number', 'timestamp', 'text line', '' (empty
    # string).
    lines = transcript.splitlines()

    # Iterate over 'lines' to get each single element from it. Divide the
    # range object by 4 because of the 'lines' object's structure: (0: line
    # number, 1: timestamp, 2: text line, 3: empty string).
    for x in range(int(len(lines) / 4)):
        # Increment iterable by 4. The * sign allows to always move 4
        # elements further to the next "profanity cycle".
        x = x * 4
        # Add relevant elements to lists.
        line_numbers.append(lines[x])
        timestamps.append(lines[x + 1])
        text_lines.append(lines[x + 2])
        
    # Iterate over transcript data and create a zip object.
    for line_number, timestamp, text_line in zip(line_numbers, timestamps,
                                                 text_lines):
        # Create a list with timestamp strings: '00:00:03,950', '-->',
        # '00:00:06,840'.
        time_splits = timestamp.split()

        for swearword in wordlist.splitlines():
            # Iterate over tokenized text lines.
            for word in text_line.split():
                if word == swearword:
                    profanity_output.append([word, f"{time_splits[0]}", 
                                             f"{time_splits[2]}",
                                             censor_chars])

    return profanity_output

# Call function.
profanity_output = create_profanity_output()
print(profanity_output)
```

Comment: Can we see your input?

Comment: You should definitely change the way you do your swearword lookup though. Would be better to parse the `wordlist` once as a `set` and see if `word in swearword_set`.

Comment: Just switch the nested for-loops `for swearword...` and `for word...`. The outer loop controls the order.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Yay, now it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Michael Butscher in the comments, your problem is that the `for loops` are in the wrong order. Currently, the ordering of your swearword list determines the order that words in the same `text_line` will be added. Switching the ordering of the loops will give you the correct ordering.

However, the better solution is to parse your swearwords beforehand. This will still maintain the order of words as ordered in the `text_line` but will also speed up the lookup (and is just better practice, even if you don't need the speed).

```py
swearwords = set(wordlist.splitlines())
for word in text_line.split():
    if word in swearwords:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanation, and also for the additional tip on parsing the swearwords. I will adjust this in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your output for the same line is actually ordered by the order of profanities in `wordlist`. So you first pick a profanity and then go through the line to see if it exists. You actually need to iterate over the line first. You can also use the [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) function of a list to see if your word is actually a swearword.

Like so:

```py
        swearwords = wordlist.splitlines()
        # Iterate over tokenized text lines.
        for word in text_line.split():
            if word in swearwords:
                profanity_output.append([word, f"{time_splits[0]}", 
                                         f"{time_splits[2]}",
                                         censor_chars])
```